# Is there a way to mock the state in react for unit testing without using enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I've been using jest and have been reading through the @testing-library/react docs but so far found nothing relating to mocking state in react. I know mocking state in react is possible with enzyme. But I'm using react 18 and there is no enzyme-adapter for this version. I'm quite new to unit testing and would love to get some suggestions on this.

Comment: _Don't_ mock state. Test components as they're used, via the public API.